# Cannot compile env_logger 0.3.5 on a computer without Internet access: cannot find function 'set_logger' in module 'log'

Tags: logging, compiler-errors, rust, rust-cargo

I'm attempting to compile my Rust code on an isolated network. The exact same code compiles fine on an internet-connected computer, but breaks when building `env_logger` in the isolated network:

```
cargo new project_name; 
cd project_name; 
echo 'env_logger = "0.3.5"' >> Cargo.toml; 
cargo build
```

Which outputs (forgive typos, I had to copy this by hand):

```
Created library 'project_name' project
Updating registry 'http://registry-url/'
Compiling winapi v0.2.8
Compiling regex-syntax v0.3.9
Compiling utf8-ranges v0.1.3
Compiling cfg-if v0.1.2
Compiling libc v0.2.36
Compiling winapi-build v0.1.1
Compiling log v0.4.1
Compiling kernel32-sys v0.2.2
Compiling log v0.3.9
Compiling memchr v0.1.11
Compiling aho-corasick v0.5.3
Compiling thread-id v2.0.0
Compiling thread_local v0.2.7
Compiling regex v0.1.80
Compiling env_logger v0.3.5
error[E0425]: cannot find function 'set_logger' in module 'log'
--> /home/username/.cargo/registry/src/registry-url-hash/env_logger-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:255:14
    |
255 | log::set_logger(|max_level| {
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in 'log'

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile 'env_logger'
```

I've verified that log is successfully downloaded into my local .cargo registry, and if I open `log-0.4.1/src/lib.rs` I can find `pub fn set_logger...` on line 1045. If I open `log-0.3.9/src/lib.rs` I find `pub fn set_logger<M>` on line 701.

If I look at `/home/username/.cargo/registry/src/registry-url-hash/env_logger-0.3.5/Cargo.toml`, it says this in the dependencies:

```
log = { version = "0.3", path = ".." }.
```

I've tried removing the `path` argument with no change in behavior, and tried setting version to "0.4" also with no change. I also tried purging the cache directory and rebuilding from a fresh download just to make sure I didn't mess anything up.

Here is my version info:

> env_logger: 0.3.5
>
> log: 0.4.1
>
> rustc: 1.24.0 (4d90ac38c 2018-02-12)
>
> cargo: 0.25.0 (8c93e0895 2018-02-01)

If I add `set_logger` to the `use log::{...}` line in the `env_logger/src/lib.rs` file, I get a "not found" error consistent with the above compiler error.

I don't know precisely how to reproduce this issue besides trying to compile a project with `env_logger = "0.3.5"` in your Cargo.toml (which doesn't cause any problems for me in general). Any idea what might be causing this issue? How can I troubleshoot what's going on?

For background information, we mirrored the Cargo registry on the isolated network. With a few tweaks to `.cargo/config`, I can get my computer to reach to our mirror instead of trying to reach out onto the internet (which it can't). This computer is completely airgapped.

Comment: @Shepmaster MCVE: `cargo new project_name; cd project_name; echo 'env_logger = "0.3.5"' >> Cargo.toml; cargo build`. The libraries' source files are downloading properly and a bunch of other sub-dependencies compile correctly, so it's odd that env_logger specifically (and co-workers have reported a couple other libraries that behave similarly) fails to build. That's why I'm asking for help to even figure out what else to consider trying.

Comment: The MCVE posted above produces exactly the error I pasted into the question. The error is produced while compiling `env_logger` as a dependency (whether implicit or explicit) of my code (which, as demonstrated by the MCVE, is nothing specific). I can't copy-paste (seeing as the computer has no internet), but give me a sec and I'll try to re-type the MCVE exact output as exactly as I can.

Comment: The computer isn't connected to *another* computer with internet, it's completely airgapped? You can't save to a file and stick it on a USB drive? That's rough.

Comment: How did you get the source code of all the dependencies from the internet onto this non-internet connected computer in the first place?

Comment: We mirrored the cargo registry on the isolated network. With a few tweaks to `.cargo/config` I can get my computer to reach to our mirror instead of trying to reach out onto the internet (which it can't). And yes, completely airgapped.

Comment: `log = { version = "0.3", path = ".." }`. I've tried removing the `path` argument with no change in behavior, and tried setting version to "0.4" also with no change. I also tried purging the cache directory and rebuilding from a fresh download just to make sure I didn't mess anything up.

Comment: Could you check if `Cargo.lock` is the same between the two machines? And try `rustup show` *in the source tree* on both machines to make sure there isn't a `rustup override` in effect.